# data rendering issues using ionic2 Virtual Scroll

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using the ionic2 Virtual Scroll for showing pagination. we are getting the issues while rendering the data in HTML.

we are able to fetch the JSON data but data is not rendering. 
could any one help on this issue?

### HTML file

```
<ion-list class="listview" [virtualScroll]="txndata">   
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let txn">         
    <ion-grid>                
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-33>
          <strong>Txn Id:</strong>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-75>
          {{txn.custRefId}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>   
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

### component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'transactions',
  templateUrl: 'transactions.html'   
})

export class TransactionsPage {
  public txndata: Array<any> = [];
  public txndataarray: any = [];
  constructor(){
    this.getAllTransactionDetails();
  }

  public getAllTransactionDetails(){
    this.commonServices.getTransactionDetails()    
     .subscribe(
       data => {    
         this.txndataarray = data.content;
         for(let txndataObj of this.txndataarray) {            
            this.txndata.push(txndataObj);         
          }     
       },
       err => {    
       },
       () => console.log()
   );
}
```

### service

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonServices {
  constructor(){

  }
   getTransactionDetails() {
        let url = '/gettxnmasterdetails';
        return this.getMethod(url);
      }

      getMethod(url: any){        
        return this.http.get(url,"some headers").map(
          result => {
            let data = result.json();
            return data;
          }
          )
      }
}
```

and output i am getting is,

`[{"custRefId":"159025"},{"custRefId":"1525"},{"custRefId":"9025"}]`

Comment: "getting the issues while rendering " what issue exactly? any errors?

Comment: sorry for the late reply..i am not getting any errors but the data is not rendering and showing the blank screen. But i am able to display the response. {{txndata | json}}

Comment: hope it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a virtual scroll issue at all.
Take a look at [this Github link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6861) and also [this forum discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/placing-ion-grid-inside-ion-item-showing-empty-rows/53690)
Both suggest `ion-grid` does not get rendered within `ion-item`.

As @jgw96 suggests in the github link:

> after discussing this with my teammates it seems to be partly by
>   design, and partly an angular issue that this does not work. As a
>   workaround for this i would recommend not using ion-grid and just use
>   css to do your layout.

Suggest you go with `ion-item` as you would need the `ion-list` for virtual-scroll and use custom css for arranging the items.

```
ion-list class="listview" [virtualScroll]="txndata">   
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let txn">         
          <strong>Txn Id:</strong>
          {{txn.custRefId}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```